# Nested Form doesn't show assignments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I recently followed a tutorial about nested forms by [Ryan Bates](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and did basically the same thing as he did just with other names. I wanted to nest assignments in the order form and I would like to build an assignment for every bun to that order and the user should put a count in the form.

So my controller looks like this

```
 def new
   @order = Order.new
   @buns = Bun.all
   @buns.each do |bun|
     @order.assignments.build(:bun_id => bun.id)
   end
 end
```

And the _form partial looks like this

```
  <%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :user_id %><br />
      <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
    </div>
    <div id="assignments" class="field">
      <% f.fields_for :assignments do |builder| %>
        <div id="assignment" class="field">
          <%= builder.label :count, "Anzahl" %>
          <%= builder.text_field :count %>
          <%= builder.object.bun_id %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :due_to %><br />
      <%= f.datetime_select :due_to %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

The Order model has this part

```
has_many :assignments
has_one :user

accepts_nested_attributes_for :assignments
```

And the Assignments model this one:

```
attr_accessible :bun_id, :order_id, :count
belongs_to :bun
belongs_to :order
```

As i log the assignments out there are all, which should be build, so why weren't the fields rendered?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an equal sign (=) in your erb :

```
 <%= f.fields_for :assignments do |builder| %>
```